# Issue in creating jenkins job in saltstack

Tags: jenkins, salt-stack

I am trying to create a job on Jenkins, which is running in the salt minion. 
When i run    `salt '*' jenkins.create_job test` from salt master
I get error saying:

```
 Module 'jenkins' is not available.
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
```

can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: What is your salt version and did you synchronise from the salt-master to the minion?

Comment: @gile the salt version am using is "salt 2016.11.1 (Carbon)" and yes master and minion is under sync

Answer (score 0):

Most of modules in Saltstack if they are not available it will be because of the [`__virtual__` function](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/modules/jenkins.py#L41-L50) which is responsible for the availability of the module is returning `False`. In your case the module is trying to check if Jenkins is available on the minion by trying to [`import jenkins`](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/modules/jenkins.py#L23-L27) in python if it fails to then jenkins module will be unavailable.

So what you need to do in order to check if that is the exact case you have to run the python interpreter on the minion system then call `import jenkins` if you got the following message `No module named jenkins` then you need to make sure that [python-jenkins](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-jenkins/0.4.5) is installed on the minion system where you have Jenkins up and running. Also you can check its [documentation](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#example-1-get-version-of-jenkins) if you need to.

- **Note**: This module is for controlling `Jenkins` so you can only use it on a minion where Jenkins is installed.